# Como fazer um update com inner join no Oracle

Tags: banco-de-dados, oracle, pl-sql

Boa tarde ,

Como faço um update com inner join , pois preciso alterar o campo idnaoleitura = 24 para  idnaoleitura = 0 onde o idrota in (35,45,48,53,60,68,70,79) , lembrando o idrota esta em outra tabela.

A tabela calculo_leituras_ucb possui o campo idnaoleitura
A tabela calculo_dados possui o campo idrota
As chaves são os campos  : IDUC

calculo_leituras_ucb.iduc
calculo_dados.iduc

Segue abaixo código.

```
begin

 execute immediate 'alter table calculo_leituras_ucb disable all triggers';
 execute immediate 'alter table calculo_dados disable all triggers';

UPDATE calculo_leituras_ucb
SET calculo_leituras_ucb.idnaoleitura = 0
from calculo_leituras_ucb 
inner join calculo_dados on  calculo_leituras_ucb.iduc = calculo_dados.iduc 
where calculo_leituras_ucb.ano_mes = ('01/07/2014')
and calculo_dados.idrota in (35,45,48,53,60,68,70,79)
and calculo_leituras_ucb.idnaoleitura = 24 ;


 commit;

 execute immediate 'alter table calculo_leituras_ucb enable all triggers';
 execute immediate 'alter table calculo_dados enable all triggers';

    exception when others then
        rollback;

        execute immediate 'alter table Calculo_leituras_ucb enable all triggers';
         execute immediate 'alter table calculo_dados enable all triggers';

        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000,'tem erro no script >:( !!!.'|| sqlerrm(sqlcode));

end;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Até onde eu saiba não tem jeito em Oracle, mas pode fazer o que quer com `exists`:

```
UPDATE calculo_leituras_ucb
SET calculo_leituras_ucb.idnaoleitura = 0
where exists (
    select calculo_dados.iduc 
    from calculo_dados
    where calculo_dados.idrota in (35,45,48,53,60,68,70,79)
    and calculo_leituras_ucb.iduc = calculo_dados.iduc
)
and calculo_leituras_ucb.ano_mes = ('01/07/2014')
and calculo_leituras_ucb.idnaoleitura = 24 ;
```

Answer (score 3):

Até onde saiba não faz, uma solução é montar um cursor

```
...
FOR R IN (SELECT calculo_leituras_ucb.iduc
          from calculo_leituras_ucb 
          inner join calculo_dados on  calculo_leituras_ucb.iduc = calculo_dados.iduc 
          where calculo_leituras_ucb.ano_mes = ('01/07/2014')
          and CALCULO_DADOS.IDROTA in (35,45,48,53,60,68,70,79)
          and CALCULO_LEITURAS_UCB.IDNAOLEITURA = 24)
LOOP
  update CALCULO_LEITURAS_UCB
  set CALCULO_LEITURAS_UCB.IDNAOLEITURA = 0
  WHERE iduc = R.iduc;
end LOOP;
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Também pode ser feito com uma sub-query no in:

```
UPDATE calculo_leituras_ucb clu
   SET clu.idnaoleitura = 0
 WHERE clu.ano_mes = ('01/07/2014')
   AND clu.idnaoleitura = 24
   AND clu.iduc IN (SELECT cd.iduc
                      FROM calculo_dados cd
                     WHERE cd.idrota IN (35, 45, 48, 53, 60, 68, 70, 79));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE
(SELECT calculo_leituras_ucb.iduc
          from calculo_leituras_ucb 
          inner join calculo_dados on  calculo_leituras_ucb.iduc = calculo_dados.iduc 
          where calculo_leituras_ucb.ano_mes = ('01/07/2014')
          and CALCULO_DADOS.IDROTA in (35,45,48,53,60,68,70,79)
          and CALCULO_LEITURAS_UCB.IDNAOLEITURA = 24) DADOS
 SET DADOS.IDNAOLEITURA = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE 
(SELECT tabela_1.valor AS valor_OLD, tabela_2.valor as valor_novo
 FROM tabela_1
 INNER JOIN tabela_2
 ON tabela_1.codigo= tabela_2.codigo
) tb
SET tb.valor_OLD= tb.valor_novo
```